# Microsoft VS Android Emulator installs app but not able to run

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-emulator

I need to run my (Xamarin) android app on Microsoft Visual studio Android Emulator.

```
--Log after Build for apk is succeeds: 
2>Build succeeded.
2>Waiting for device..
2>Detecting installed packages
2>Detecting installed packages...
2>
2>Installing shared runtime
2>Target device is x86.
2>Installing the Mono shared runtime (x86 - 1443097651)...
2>
2>Installing platform framework
2>Installing the API 23 platform framework..
2>
2>Installing application on device
2>Copying application to device...
2>
2>Getting installation path...
2>Using fast dev path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.software_innovation.proarcmobile/files/.__override__
2>Synchronizing assemblies...
2>Synchronizing assemblies
```

It starts the apk in Emulator but suddenly stops the app and also debugger gets stopped without any message on output console.

I tried to start installed app without debugger attached, but doesn't start. Internet is working in Emulator. I've tried reinstalling vs_emulator.

Comment: I have this very same issue. Tried to changed properties related to "Fast Deployment" and others but nothing works

Comment: Please post the LogCat output. It will help us understand what went wrong.

Comment: Are you able to run your app on a device or other emulators?

Comment: Sorry, my comments will be delayed, as got busy with other tasks. I will come back to this.

Comment: I removed previously installed Emulator and reinstalled, so getting errors listed here: http://pastebin.com/JcabrZRf

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Xamarin Forms Android App Crashes Running Debug with VS Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800168/xamarin-forms-android-app-crashes-running-debug-with-vs-android-emulator/35779589#35779589)

In short:

- Start the Hyper-V manager
- Select the emulator you are trying to use
- Right-click, hit settings
- Click processor
- Click Compatibility
- Set checkbox “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor
  version”