# Xamarin Android: AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I debug, the emulators opens and closes de app. I found a question in stackoverflow but didn't fix my problem. 
[Xamarin Forms Android App Crashes Running Debug with VS Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800168/xamarin-forms-android-app-crashes-running-debug-with-vs-android-emulator)

```
11-01 10:04:56.554 D/Mono    ( 1396): AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/Trunk.Droid-1/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
11-01 10:04:56.554 D/Mono    ( 1396): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/Trunk.Droid-1/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
```

Any more ideas? I'm on latest version of VS and Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have `AOT` enabled for your application, these messages are completely diagnostic and do not affect anything. If anything this is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) to the actual issue. There is an outstanding issue for this here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42933

For your issue of the emulator opening and closing your application, you should get an `adb logcat` so you can figure out what the real reason is:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/