# Xamarin.Forms Android VS2017 debug not showing XAML changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, I start a brand new Xamarin.Forms solution, PCL and Blank App template.

Here is what the MainPage.xaml content looks like:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Using the Visual Studio Android emulator, I start a debug session, to confirm its working, and then close it.

Then I make a small change the MainPage.xaml file, for example:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <EntryCell Label="UserName : "></EntryCell>
    <EntryCell Label="Password : "></EntryCell>
</StackLayout>
```

And then I start  a debug session again. The emulator behaves as if I never made any changes. The app UI still says "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!".

I tried the following, and none of them change the behavior. The emulator will act as if the very first code that was sent to it is still running.

1. <s>Restart emulator</s>
2. <s>Clean/Rebuild solution</s>
3. <s>Manually delete bin and obj folders</s>
4. <s>Close VS2017 and entire VS Android emulator manager and reopen</s>
5. <s>Reboot entire PC</s>
6. <s>Everything in this answer</s> - [Xamarin Forms Android App Crashes Running Debug with VS Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800168/xamarin-forms-android-app-crashes-running-debug-with-vs-android-emulator/35779589#35779589)

If I start up a new project, do all of the above, and the exact same thing will happen. I have also tried using the default android emulators (from AVDs), and they do not work at all, when I try to debug I simply get a white screen.

Comment: Are you debugging for Any CPU? Check it in the VS debugger toolbar. Try to deploy the project. In solution explorer, right click on the project node and select Deploy. You may see error during the Deploy in the output window.

Comment: @PedroSilva you pointed me in the right direction, thank you so much. It turns out my actual issue is you cant use an EntryCell element inside a StackLayout, it can only be used as a child of a LIstView or TableView. Lets just say, the Xamarin tooling still needs a lot of work. I wasted 5-6 hours on this little mixup.